# Display selected users image from phonebook

Tags: android, xml, listview

I am creating a multi-users chat application. The Inbox activity load the list of users from XML which i used for storage.I have a problem i want that when inbox activity loads the users list it also check that whether any of these user present in phone-book or not. if any user is in phone-book then it loads the Image of that user in listview.
I solved my problem up to some extent but i am unable to display the selected user image. Please give me some hint how to do this.Thank you in advance.

Here is a snapshot of Inbox

[image: snapshot]

Inbox Activity java:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.users_index);
        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Inbox Messages");
        //getNumber(this.getContentResolver()); 
        getdata();
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) { 
                TextView uname=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.sendername);
                username = uname.getText().toString();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("username", username);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
    private void getdata() {
        try {
            File fXmlFile = new File("/data/data/net.multiplesystem.nosms/Messeges/UserList.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("details");
            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                    String a=eElement.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent().toString();
                    userIndex.add(a);
                }
                }
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setListAdapter();
    }

    private void setListAdapter(){
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.user_index_layout,R.id.sendername,userIndex);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        registerForContextMenu(listView);
    }

    /*
    public void getNumber(ContentResolver cr)
    {
        Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext())
        {
            name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            id = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
            contactId = Long.parseLong(id);
            System.out.println(".................."+phoneNumber); 
            System.out.println(".................."+name); 
            Number.add(phoneNumber);

        }
        phones.close();// close cursor
           ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.user_index_layout,R.id.sendername,Number);
         listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        setListAdapter();
    }
    */
}
```

Comment: There's a lot of answers that explain how to use a ListView as you request. Please browse the site and you'll find surely what you need.

Comment: i have search a lot but could not find the desired one. :(

Comment: Maybe you could post some code that narrow the issue then if the response that's been posted doesn't answer your question =)

Comment: sorry for the late reply,i have posted the code please check.

Answer (score 0):

try this it may help, pass the phone number to get photo

```
    public Bitmap getPhoto(String phoneNumber) {
    Uri phoneUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
    Uri photoUri = null;
    ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
    Cursor contact = cr.query(phoneUri,
            new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID }, null, null, null);

    if (contact.moveToFirst()) {
        long userId = contact.getLong(contact.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        photoUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, userId);

    }
    else {
        Bitmap defaultPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image);
        return defaultPhoto;
    }
    if (photoUri != null) {
        InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(
                cr, photoUri);
        if (input != null) {
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        }
    } else {
        Bitmap defaultPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image);
        return defaultPhoto;
    }
    Bitmap defaultPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image);
    return defaultPhoto;
}
```

Comment: how to pass bitmap object to adapter ?

Comment: hey call that method in adapter it self... at the time of setting bitmap to imageview do this.. imageView.setImageBitmap(getPhoto(999999999));

Comment: i have posted my code please check and give some suggestions.

Comment: rather than using ArrayAdapter, use custom adapter & create a model object which can store both name & object, pass this object to adapter.. At the time of setting data, u can set all the parameters & set imageview also

Answer (score 0):

What i understand from your code is that you need to inflate custom layouts for displaying contacts.
I believe your `R.layout.user_index_layout` is something like that :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    ... >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/userIndexLayout_img" 
        ... />
    <TextView
        ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

So imagine some callback that gets notified when a user becomes connected like this (more pseudo-code) :

```
public void onUserConnected(int id) {
    int indexInsideListView = getUserIndex(id);
    View userView = listView.getChildAt(indexInsideListView);
    ImageView imgView = (ImageView) userView.findViewById(R.id.userIndexLayout_img);
    // User ImageView.setImageResource/Drawable/Bitmap
}
```